# Trigger keyboard show-up Flutter

Tags: flutter, triggers, keyboard, textfield, show

I know most of the people have problems with keyboard and want it to go away, but I'm interested in it showing up. Basically, I want to trigger the keyboard show-up when I tap an element and then get the text I typed via RawKeyboard. Is there a way I can trigger the keyboard to show in Flutter? So far I understood you can do that only when you have a TextField.

Many thanks.

Comment: FocusNode isn't help you in this case?

Comment: FocusNode with the requestFocus by itself I think it doesnt. I found some example online that was using it, but it was linking to a TextField, which I dont have.